# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\AdapterInterface in magento2

Tags: magento2, https, zend-framework

```
$httpAdapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\AdapterInterface();
```

give error -

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\AdapterInterface.

Comment: You cannot interact with an interface except for accessing any defined constants in it or using it for TypeHints.

Comment: please give a example how to use it?

Comment: Why you need this adapter? for curl?

Comment: in payment method after success get all data...                                             $res = $this->_postBack($httpAdapter,$this->cgi_url.'/'.'transaccion/' . $this->_request['token'], $header_array,  $data);

Comment: protected function _postBack(Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface $httpAdapter,$url, $header_array, $data)
    {
   $result = $this->sendRequest($url, Zend_Http_Client::GET, $header_array);
  if($result){
   return $result;
  }
  else{
   throw new Exception($error);
  }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an interface, you have to choose a concrete implementation (a **class**)

The following implementations are built in:

- Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket
- Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Proxy
- Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl
- Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Test

(see: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.http.client.adapters.html )

You can instantiate one of these with "new", but usually you would not do that directly, but use the `Zend\Http\Client` class which takes care of adapter instantiation ("Socket" by default)